# Unable to add Value to python dictionary and write to a file

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to check if a word exists in the `dict`. If does not that I will add the `key` and `value` to the `dict`:

```
mydict = {}    
with io.open("fileo.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fileo:
      for Word in filei:
        Word = Word.split()
        if not Word in dict:
            dict[Word] = 1
        elif Word in dict:
            dict[Word] = dict[Word] + 1
    print [unicode(i) for i in dict.items()]
```

It throws below error:

```
if not Word in dict:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

If I remove the `Word = Word.split()` part it works, but entire line is considered. That will not help me. I want to count every word as you can see.

Comment: Where have you declared `dict`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Word = Word.split()` will make `Word` a list, and you cannot have a `list` (or any other unhashable type) as a dictionary key.

You should consider using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), but to slightly modify your existing code:

```
with io.open("fileo.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as filei:
    d = dict()
    for line in filei:
        words = line.strip().split()
        for word in words:
            if word in d:
                d[word] += 1
            else:
                d[word] = 1
    print d
    print [unicode(i) for i in d.items()]
```

Comment: Thanks. in the modified code you gave, don't we have to declare:
`dict = {} `

Comment: @Dinakar No, the dict I made is called `d`. Do not make a variable named `dict` or you are shadowing the Python keyword.

Comment: I have edited the code. It's actually not dict, but `mydict = {}`.

I am still learning python. To clarify, when u say `mydict = dict()`, it's like creating a new `mydict = {}`

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I am basically writing `d` to a file:

`mydictfile.write(unicode(d.items()))`

Can we add some additional words to key values:

For example, if the ` ('face':10) ` is what is stored. Can I have some thing like `(d1:'face':10) ` How can we do it.

Another thing is, even if I have stored in the file, it still going to remain in buffer for accessing for some other purpose right?

Comment: Also for me the data is getting stored as (u'Kate', 12). I guess that u is for unicode. How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have split on words, you can do the check and count by using a for loop:

```
words = Word.split()
for word in words:
    if not word in dict:
        ...
```

But since you are just counting words, I would recommend using a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead:

from collections import Counter

```
with io.open("fileo.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    word_count = Counter()
    for line in f:
        words = line.strip.split()
        word_count.update(words)
    print [unicode(word) for word in d.most_common(100)]
```

This will count unique words and print the 100 most frequent words at the end.

It can be written shorter (if your file is not too big, since the whole file is read at once):

```
with io.open("fileo.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    word_count = Counter(word.strip() for word in f.read().split())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to import and use a `defaultdict` or a `Counter` dict use `dict.setdefault` and avoid the need for the `if/else`. Use the word string as the key:

```
dct = {}    
with io.open("fileo.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fileo:
      for line in filei:
          words = line.split()
          for word in words:
              word = word.lower() 
              # if key does not exist add it and set a default value of 0
              dct.setdefault(word, 0)
              dct[word] += 1 #  increment the count
```

Use lowercase names for variable and don't use `dict` as a variable name as it shadows the python `dict`. I presume you consider `Word` and `word` to be the same so you need to call lower on each word to catch any cases where the word has uppercase letters.

If you want to store the dict to a file  use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pickle.html) or [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import pickle
with open("count.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(dct ,f)
```

To load simply:

```
with open("count.pkl", "rb") as f:
   dct = pickle.load(f)
```

Using json for human readable output in the file:

```
import json
with open("count.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(dct,f)


with open("count.json") as f:
    dct = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Basically I would eventually want to save this dict to a file and read it later.. is that possible?

Comment: @Dinakar, yep, do you want it in human readable format  in the file or does in not matter?