# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not dict - nested values in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a code with multiple keys and value in python dict. For example, my dict will look like this:

```
d={"p1": {"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15}}, "p2": {"d1":{"python":14,"Programming":15}} }
```

Here I have a method that populates dictionary if a particular value does not exists.
Here is how the code looks like:

[Unable to add Value to python dictionary and write to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516906/unable-to-add-value-to-python-dictionary-and-write-to-a-file)

I modified my function to accept 1 parameter. For example my parameter is

How do update the dictionary in this case?

I tried :

```
FunDictr(d1)
#say the calling function passed 'foo'
#means d1 = foo

    with io.open("fileo.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as filei:
        d = dict()
        for line in filei:
            words = line.strip().split()
            for word in words:
                if word in d:
                    d[d1][word] += 1
                else:
                    d[d1][word] = 1
```

I am expecting to see {"foo": {"d1":{"python":14}}

When I write this, I get error:

```
d[d1][word] += 1
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not dict
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Just to clarify d1 is a variable representing a string passed to the calling function?

Comment: @NickBailey Yes we can say that

Comment: Where is it assigned, I don't see any place in your function as you've put it up here that assigns a value to d1 and it is not being passed as a parameter to the function. Are you use a global variable here?

Comment: I will call my function from some other module as funDictr(foo).
Calling function  = cFun('foo')

so called function has cFun(d).

so d = foo

Comment: Gotcha, but the arguement in funDictr is d not d1, is this a typo?

Comment: oh yes, I corrected it now

Comment: Your `d[d1]` is `list` type right now. You should change it to `dict`.

Comment: @ozgur I am a newbee, can you please share the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample you gave, it looks like you are looking for something a little like this.

```
def FunDictr(base_dictionary,string_key):
    d = dict()
    d[string_key] = dict()
    d[string_key]["d1"] = dict()
    with io.open("fileo.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as filei:   
        for line in filei:
            words = line.strip().split()
            for word in words:
                if word in d[string_key]["d1"]:
                    d[string_key]["d1"][word] += 1
                else:
                    d[string_key]["d1"][word] = 1
```

This will accept an initial dictionary, add a new item with the key passed to the function, create a nested dictionary as the value of that key with a key of the string d1, then create ANOTHER dictionary inside of that which holds the word counts.

Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of the extra layer of nesting? Why not shoot for.

{'foo':{'python':14}}

Also, I strongly suggest more descriptive variable names. It makes life easier :)

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you! I actually changed naming so it's shorter and can the text box here can accept more data.  I don't see base_dictionary used any where... where is it used? Why is it called.. I guess you've put that assuming some thing.. I am not clear on that.. For my requirement I am fine with {'foo':{'python':14}}.. but later I might continue to add, but again it depends.. I am not sure how to achieve this too: {'foo':{'python':14}}